# appendTo() not working in chromium 14 linux

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append data into `<h5>` tag in below manner..

```
$('<h5>').text(data[key].age).appendTo('#myContainer' + i);
```

but in chromium 14 for linux, this type of chaining doesn't work so i'll have to use..

```
var x = $('<h5>').text(key);
x.appendTo('#imageContainer' + i);
```

What would be the best alternative for this ??  and is there a way so that i can emulate
different version of chrome(windows)

Comment: Can you see youe blank h5 in the page ?

Comment: Are you sure this issue is related to Chrome? If `data[key].age` (or `key` in your second code snippet) is `undefined`, you will end up calling the getter form of `text()`, which does not chain. That might explain your problem.

Comment: i guess so .. because the same code works in all other updated browsers i even tried in firefox 3.x & chromium 19 it worked ..

Comment: @heera the page won't load and it throws error .. appendTo cannot be used with the element defined..